# Kotlin - Functional (SAM) interfaces VS Function types

Tags: kotlin

With Kotlin 1.4 we now have Functional Interfaces

```
fun interface Todo {
       fun run()
}

fun runBlock(todo: Todo){
   if(condition)
      todo.run()

}

fun runBlock{
   println("Hello world")
}
```

Before i was always using (T) -> T

```
inline fun runBlock(block: ()-> Unit){
   if(condition)
      block()
}

fun runBlock{
   println("Hello world")
}
```

So basically I can make the same task with both methods , there is any performance advantage by using Functional SAM() Interfaces over  Function Type?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a performance *dis*-advantage because the lambda is no longer inlined (unless the JIT decides to, but it won't be instant). Even if you mark `runBlock` as `inline`, the compiler will warn you that the argument won't be inlined.

There are only two reasons to use fun interfaces instead of function types:

1. Backwards compatibility when porting code using Java functional interfaces.
2. Not exposing Kotlin function types in API intended for use from Java.

To expand on point 1: before Kotlin 1.4 it was advised to keep functional interfaces as Java code, even if all your other code was Kotlin. This way you could use lambdas for parameters of those types both in Java and Kotlin code. But if you declared the interface in Kotlin, you could only use lambdas for them in Java.

Comment: There's one more reason to use functional interfaces; less boilerplate code to write. This is demonstrated in the docs. Not every lambda can be inlined (size is one constraint, there are others), and without a performance comparison, any "better or worse" comments are merely theoretical. OP's question is vague, so he got an equally generic answer from me.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar 1. No, size is not a constraint as far as I know; in `inline fun runBlock(block: ()-> Unit)` the lambda will definitely be inlined and if it can't be it won't compile.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar 2. "less boilerplate code to write. This is demonstrated in the docs." Compared to using the same interface without `fun interface`, not compared to using function types. The question is explicitly about comparing with function types.

Comment: "_size is not a constraint as far as I know_". I'm afraid you might know wrong. Lambdas are converted into method calls (refer to Brian Goetz's excellent [Translation of Lambda Expressions](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html)). Goetz doesn't discuss lambda inlining, but method inlining depends on `-XX:MaxInlineSize` and `-XX:FreqInlineSize` JVM flags. Based on both, we can conclude that lambda inlining depends on size.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar This is about Java, _not about Kotlin_. Of course inlining decision by JIT depends on size, but that has nothing to do with how Kotlin's `inline` keyword works.

Answer (score 2):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces

> the compiler automatically converts the lambda to an instance of the class that implements the abstract member function.

So, no performance advantage, it’s the same thing as before. The compiler now does what you had to do before.

Comment: " it’s the same thing as before. The compiler now does what you had to do before." this would be true if "before" code had used `Todo` interface and looked like `runBlock(object : Todo { ... })`. It doesn't, so it isn't the same thing as before.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers and comments have pointed out, in your case, using inlined lambda is faster, since there is no function call overhead when invoking it.

However, there is one specific use case where using SAM interface is **faster**, that is when you 1. **do not inline the lambda** and 2. the arguments/return value of the lambda is a primitive (or any other type that may cause boxing when used with generics).

For example, using SAM interface like so:

```kotlin
fun interface Foo() {
    fun run(i: Int): Int
}

fun foo(fn: Foo) {
    fn.run(42)
}

foo { it * 2 }
```

Will not cause any boxing when invoked, while:

```kotlin
fun foo(fn: (Int) -> Int) {
    fn(42)
}

foo { it * 2 }
```

Will box the integer argument since `(Int) -> Int` is essentially `Function1<Integer, Integer>` in Java, which uses generic.